# Why the mismatch between the EUROMOMO mortality rate and 'COVID-19 second wave' positive tests and hospitalizations?

Tags: covid-19, statistics, mortality-rate

Currently (September/October 2020) there is a large increase in the percentage of COVID-19 tests that come out positive, at least in several countries in Europe.  And, at least in the Netherlands, both the number of hospitalizations and ICU admissions linked to COVID-19 are increasing.

(For the positive test percentage in Europe, see the spreadsheet on https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/covid-19-testing, column 'positivity_rate'.  For hospitalizations and ICU admissions in the Netherlands, see https://coronadashboard.rijksoverheid.nl/ (in Dutch), sections 'Ziekenhuisopnames per dag' and 'intensive care-opnames per dag'.)

On the other hand, the EUROMOMO data (https://www.euromomo.eu/graphs-and-maps) doesn't show any unusual mortality increase (except perhaps starting last week, week 41, in Spain), after mid-August.

Where does this mismatch come from?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate (and on a different SE site), but do the answers (and comments) to https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/96287/is-the-coronavirus-getting-less-dangerous help?